# Best way to save images which comes from server in android

Tags: android, file, bitmap, android-sqlite, android-image

I am working on one application and getting product images from the server. *Currently I am saving those images into the SQLite database after converting them into byte array and at the time of use I convert them back into bitmap.*

Now I have below two queries:

1. What is the best way to save the images in app from where we can sync them also and get when ever required.
2. How to assign them on image view or button because sometimes memory issue arises and application stop suddenly.

Please guide me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: storing blob in sqlite is bad practices.Rather store images on sdcard. And store the path of image in database rather bytearray.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia ok can you provide any helpful sample for that. And also what about the 2nd issue ?

Comment: second issue is raise because of blob.Because it requires more memory to serilize and deserilize this byte object.

Comment: I am using androidquery framework for this scenario.You can download jar from here http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

Comment: @BirajZalavadia thanks but please tell me what's the purpose of this .jar file ? and how to use it ?

Comment: this jar has ready made functions to download image store into sdcard.And when you try to load image from same url it will take it from sdcard.

Answer (score 4):

Storing app specific things on SD Card may not be the right way..
You should store images on

```
// it will reside in data/data/com.package.name 
String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/";
File imagesFolder = new File(path);
imagesFolder.mkDir();
```

and put image files here in that folder.. So SD Card dependency can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Demo code

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AQuery androidQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        androidQuery = new AQuery(this);
        androidQuery.id(img).image(imgUrl, true, true);// donload and save to sdcard if it is already in sdcard will not download again.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save them as a file on the external storage:

```
File downloadDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppName/MyImages");
if(!downloadDir.exists()){
   downloadDir.mkdirs();
}
```

will create a directory to store the pictures in.

Then check out this [guide here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) how to load only the right amount of pixels for your Image. Else you will get an OutOfMemory exception. (5MP picture will take up to 20MB of the heap)